# Запретить параллельный вход

Tags: php, сессия, логин

Мне нужно, чтобы после входа на сайт пользователя под его учётными данными другой человек не смог войти на сайт используя те-же данные, пока активна сессия первого вошедшего. Соответственно, и сам человек не сможет сидеть например с одного компа но с двух разных браузеров.

Сам думаю в сторону сессий, а конкретно - в торону того, чтобы хранить ID сессии в базе рядом с логином и паролем, но тут такая проблема - если пользователь не нажал кнопку "выход", а просто закрыл вкладку, то его сессия не удалится из БД, и он уже не сможет сам-же войти например с телефона или другого ПК.

Есть вариант задать некое время активности сессии, и обновлять эту метку при каждом запросе к сайту, и если время создания прошлой метки раньше, чем текущее время минус время активности, то старая сессия считается не валидной и перезаписывается новой.

Проблема в том, что сайт написан давно и без каких-либо фреймворков, единой точки в приложение нет, есть 200+ файлов, начинающихся с `session_start();` (речь идёт о РНР). Подскажите, нет ли более элегантного решения проблемы?

Comment: поставить время жизни cookie с сессией на 1 час  `session_start(array('cookie_lifetime' =>360))` где то так

Comment: хорошо, поставили. я зашёл на сайт под теми-же учётными данными, получил один-в-один такую-же куку с `lifetime=3600`, но другим `PHPSESSID`. А как запретить вообще повторный вход? Или Ваше предложение продолжает мой подход?

Comment: Именно, но не совсем пойму зачем такие заморочки. Если это crm можно и ограничить вход по ip допустим. Или же 2-х факторная аунтификация.

Comment: Задачу нужно решать именно в таком ключе. Распоряжение сверху :))) ну, вы меня понимаете

Comment: Вам никто не мешает вместе с ID писать в БД время, до которого он действителен и при каждом входе пользователя это время обновлять

Comment: Можете сделать массовую замену `session_start()` на `include_once('/session_start.php')` :)

Comment: @rjhdby ну это да :) в эту сторону я тоже уже подумал :) само собой

Comment: При попытке логина надо проверить все активные сессии на сайте. В лоб не сделать, нодо читать файлы сессий SESSIONID, десерелиазовать данные оттуда, проверить, имеет ли юзер запущенную сессию и предупредить, что все остальные его запущенные сессии будут закрыты.

Comment: @KAGG Design не надо. нам надо посылать на 403 тех, кто пытается зайти, пока первый активен, а не разлогинивать первого

Comment: Ну и кто мешает юзера послать на 403 после того, как вы проверили все сессии и увидели, что он уже залогинен. Но это неправильно. Вот я юзер ваш, залогинился с компа на работе, а потом поехал домой. Пытаюсь с телефона зайти - 403. Да я больше на ваш сайт не приду вообще )  Надо давать юзеру право выбора

Comment: Вы не юзер, Вы манагер)) не придёте на нашу админку мы Вас уволим)) а если серьёзно, то в том-то и дело, надо давать юзеру некий интервал неактивности (15-30 мин) на протяжении которых он будет считаться активным. Хотите по пути с работы заходить? милости просим, надавили на сцылку "Выход" на сайте и вуаля, заходите хоть с калькулятора)))